# HTML margin affecting fixed element on left-hand side only

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML document (snip):

```
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <header class="main-header">
        <div>
            <a href="../index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                uHost
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed the following.

If I apply the following style:

```
background {
    background: url('../images/macbook.jpeg');
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then the background image covers the whole viewport as expected.

If I then add:

```
html {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

The margin is correctly applied to the left and right of my content. But also to the left side only of the background. Ie:
[image]

I am confused as to why, as I thought *fixed* elements were positioned relative to the viewport? So why is a style on the html element influencing the rendering of the background?

As a solution to get what I wanted (some margin on both sides), I can do something like:

```
html {
    width: 80vw;
    margin: auto;
}

.background {
    background: url('../images/macbook.jpeg');
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 80vw;

}
```

Which produces:

[image]

But again, I'm unsure why the margin property on the html element is affecting my fixed background div?

Answer (score 0):

When using position fixed, the element will still follow its natural initial placement, unless otherwise specified via the `top` `left` `bottom` or `right` attributes. Here you can see, even though the body element has a margin of `10px`, the background element is still at the top left.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

.background {
  background-image:         url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/22/Solar_Eclipse_May_20%2C2012.jpg/1024px-Solar_Eclipse_May_20%2C2012.jpg"); 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background">
    <h1> Solar Eclipse </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But with a fixed position the element *doesn't* follow it's original placement? "The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport," https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: "It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport", so its initially placed where it would normally be placed unless you specify a top,left, bottom, or right.